# how to read a plot and extract information using python

Tags: python, plot, ocr

One can use python to create a simple plot:

```
x=[1,4,6,8]
y=[4,7,9,101]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

I just started work with OCR and pytesseract, and wonder if there is a package out there that can take the line graph created above as input  (or another, bar plots, historgrams, etc) and return the corresponding x and y values. (ie, return an approximate value for points x=[1,6,8] return possible values of y=[1,6,100], which is how I eyeball the resulting plot).

Any suggestions of where to read/look would be great.

Comment: Is the input line graph is image?

Comment: yes. A plot in a pdf paper for example

Comment: I don't think that there is any such package that can do this directly. The line on the graph is formed by many points, how can you just by looking at the graph tell which are those points from many points!!!